# How to configure my own server dns?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 11.10 installed which hosts several sites. The DNS is configured under the name of company which I purchased it. For example:

`ns1.company.com`
`ns2.company.com`

I would like of to have custom name servers for my site on this VPS, such as `ns1.mysite.com`, etc. How do I do this? Thank you!

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Are you trying to run your own nameservers? Are you trying to control how your server resolves names? Or are you trying to control how others resolve your domain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things

- Configure Bind (or other DNS software) to be authoritative for your domain (zone)
- Get your registrar to delegate authority to your name server

Then you also should get secondary DNS service.

Some registrars offers DNS service

Comment: He wants to configure his *server*'s DNS, not his *domain*'s DNS.

Comment: I think he wants to be able to tell people "Goto to my website www.mycompany.com!"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Well he doesn't want to alter his server's DNS client settings, but his domain's registered nameserver details, using an alias.  He needs to edit his domain DNS, doesn't he?

Comment: As I read his question, he wants to use his own nameservers on his own server. I don't see anything that suggests any domain's registered nameserver details are involved.

Comment: if it's unclear what the quesion is about: ask OP in the comments to the question.